# FirebaseStorage.net does not completely uploads an Image

Tags: c#, android, firebase, stream, firebase-storage

I simply have a function that uploads an image to firebase:

```
public async void SaveImage(Stream stream)
    {
        var task = new FirebaseStorage("XXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com")
            .Child("images")
            .Child("users")
            .Child("name.JPG")
            .PutAsync(stream);

    }
```

And onActivityResult where I get the stream and call saveImage:

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if ((requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(this.ContentResolver, data.Data);

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 10, stream);

                    SaveImage(stream);

                }

            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException e)
            {
                //Exception Handling
            }

        }
    }
```

So it attempts to save the image to firebase but the size of the successfully save image is 0B. So does anyone have an Idea of why does the saved Image doesn't actually have the Image data saved? Thanks for any help.

Comment: check your FirebaseStorage rules .

Comment: The rules are basically no auth needed read and write is true, I'm thinking it has to do something with stream, but the stream I'm trying to save is not null and has big size. idk